# MongoDB | Graph Lookup with arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB - Trying to go a graph lookup with an array as a linking field. Seeing strange results that's difficult to comprehend.

My dataset:

```
db.events.insertMany([
  { _id: 1, name: 'A', companies: ["X", "Y", "Z"] },
  { _id: 2, name: 'B', companies: ["X", "Y"] },
  { _id: 3, name: 'C', companies: ["X", "W"] },
  { _id: 4, name: 'D', companies: ["P","Q"] },
  { _id: 5, name: 'E', companies: ["P"] }
]);
```

My graph query:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 5 } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: 'events',
      startWith: '$companies', 
      connectFromField: 'companies',
      connectToField: 'companies', 
      maxDepth: 1, 
      as: 'colleagues'
    }
  }
]);
```

Expected Result:
I'd have expected only E & D to have shown up in the results as they are the only colleagues starting from E. But it shows up everyone. 
Interestingly, if I change the datatype of companies from being an array to a single string, then it works as expected. Can an array --> array traversal be possible? Or should it require some kind of a "pre-transformation" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the maxDepth field to 0 as it is equivalent to a non-recursive $graphLookup search stage.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#max-depth

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that I was asking for the second degree connections (maxdepth=1) so it was bringing colleagues' colleagues.